# Bash string while loop

Tags: bash, shell

Is there anyway to do while(string) just like what is in c

In c we have null terminator, but I'm not sure whether bash has it

while [ $string ] in bash will terminate when there is a space, which is not what I want, how do I detect whether it reaches the end of string or not?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The answer to your question may very well be "Yes, there is a way". Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on improving this question. Meta-code, even, or working code in a language with which you're more familiar, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. If you can, try to make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can have some confidence we're actually working on the right problem.

Comment: That said, is this the kind of thing you're looking for? `x="Hello"; for ((i=0; i<${#x}; i++)) { printf '> %s\n' "${x:$i:1}"; }`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the loop is removing part of the string and that it should stop when the string is empty.  The way to do that in Bash is:

```
while [[ $string ]]
```

or (more explicitly)

```
while [[ -n $string ]]
```

For shells that don't have `[[...]]` the equivalent is

```
while [ "$string" ]
```

or

```
while [ -n "$string" ]
```

The quotes are necessary to prevent various problems,  including incorrect termination when the string contains only characters from `$IFS` (including, normally, the space character).  Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on shell code to detect many quoting problems, including the one in the question ([SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086)).